# How to restore screen to normal size?

Tags: applications, screen

A friend asked me to help fix her phone. She left it with her kid and they put it on safe mode.

I restarted it and it went into a smaller screen display like this.

[image: IMG:]

(Tap to enlarge)

Without trying a factory reset anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please [edit] your question and include at least: The device you're using, Android version it is running. Also check and update the tags you've used to match your issue.

Comment: See if there is a setting to change the display size under Settings > Display. Otherwise, you would have to use [tag:adb] I think to fix this. `adb shell wm overscan reset` should be able to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

My phone also has this feature. It is called one-handed operation. Go to Settings → Advanced Features. There you will find this option. Alternatively, you can search in settings.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for your specific device but an old LG G4 (VS986) I used to have had an option in "Developer Options" to set a custom resolution (DPI to be specific).
I highly doubt your friend's kid was able to change this, especially if developer options was never unlocked.